# Get-Service in a Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

A basic question - but why in a Powershell Script does Get-Service not print the list to the output?

```
    Write-Host "Enumerating installed Services..." -ForegroundColor Green
    Get-Service | Sort-Object status,displayname
```

Now in the script it gives no output at all.

But if I opened a powershell prompt and typed it manually it works fine.

Full Script:

```
param([string] $server)

$serverSystem = Get-WmiObject -computername $env:computername Win32_ComputerSystem
$serverCPUDetail = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $env:computername Win32_Processor

switch ($ComputerSystem.DomainRole){
        0 {$ComputerRole = "Standalone Workstation"}
        1 {$ComputerRole = "Member Workstation"}
        2 {$ComputerRole = "Standalone Server"}
        3 {$ComputerRole = "Member Server"}
        4 {$ComputerRole = "Domain Controller"}
        5 {$ComputerRole = "Domain Controller"}
        default {$ComputerRole = "No role available" }
    }


$serverOS = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $env:computername

Write-Host "Enumerating  System information..." -ForegroundColor Green
" "
Start-Sleep -s 1
Write-Host "Hostname:" ($env:computername)
Write-Host "Domain:" ($serverSystem.Domain)
Write-Host "Role:" ($ComputerRole)
Write-Host "Operating System:" ($serverOS.Caption)
Write-Host "Service Pack:" ($serverOS.CSDVersion)
$lastBootTime = $serverOS.ConvertToDateTime($serverOS.Lastbootuptime)
Write-Host "Last Boot Time:" $lastBootTime
" "
Write-Host "Enumerating  Hardware information..." -ForegroundColor Green
" "
Start-Sleep -s 1
Write-Host "Model:" ($serverSystem.Model)
Write-Host "Manufacturer:" ($serverSystem.Manufacturer)
Write-Host "CPU - No. of Processors:" ($serverSystem.NumberOfProcessors)
Write-Host "CPU - No. of Cores:" ($serverCPUDetail.NumberofCores)
Write-Host "CPU - No. of Processors, Logical:" ($serverCPUDetail.NumberOfLogicalProcessors)
Write-Host "Memory in GB:" ([math]::round($serverSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1024/1024/1024,0))

" "
Write-Host "Enumerating Disk Information..." -ForegroundColor Green
Start-Sleep -s 1
Foreach ($s in $env:computername) {
    Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -cn $s |
    Select-Object @{LABEL='Comptuer';EXPRESSION={$s}},DriveLetter, Label,@{LABEL='Free Space (GB)';EXPRESSION={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.freespace/1GB)}} 
}
" "
Write-Host "Enumerating Network Information..." -ForegroundColor Green
" "
Start-Sleep -s 1 
ForEach($NIC in $env:computername) {
    $intIndex = 1
    $NICInfo = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $env:computername Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object {$_.IPAddress -ne $null}
    $caption = $NICInfo.Description 
    $ipAddress = $NICInfo.IPAddress
    $ipSubnet = $NICInfo.IpSubnet 
    $ipGateWay = $NICInfo.DefaultIPGateway 
    $macAddress = $NICInfo.MACAddress 
    Write-Host "Network Card": $intIndex
    Write-Host "Interface Name: $caption"
    Write-Host "IP Addresses: $ipAddress" 
    Write-Host "Subnet Mask: $ipSubnet"
    Write-Host "Default Gateway: $ipGateway"
    Write-Host "MAC: $macAddress"
    $intIndex += 1
}
" "
# Write-Host "Enumerating Software Installations..." -ForegroundColor Green
# "  "
# Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -property Name

Write-Host "Enumerating installed Services..." -ForegroundColor Green
Get-Service | Sort-Object status,displayname
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? As you mentioned in your question it does work fine, what is the issue?

Comment: Basically in the script it won't print anything, but if I open a manual powershell prompt, it works fine.

Comment: There is not problem with these two line of codes. They produce output inside or outside of a script. It's something else you are not showing that is causing problem. Please post your script and please post how you are calling it.

Comment: Added, it's called right at a bottom, just like the post, nothing special

Comment: yep, I can see the problem. I know how to fix it and I'm *guessing* what's causing it, though I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you posted is fine. It's something else that you are not showing that does not work.

Try this:

```
$script = @"
Write-Host "Enumerating installed Services..." -ForegroundColor Green
Get-Service | Sort-Object status,displayname
"@

$script | Set-Content ./test.ps1
./test.ps1
```

The above writes your two lines in a script file and then executes the script. As you would expect it produces desired output.

**Update 1**

Having seen the input, I can now reproduce the problem. Basically if you run this:

```
$a= Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -cn $s | 
  Select-Object @{LABEL='Comptuer';EXPRESSION={$s}},DriveLetter, Label,@{LABEL='Free Space (GB)';EXPRESSION={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.freespace/1GB)}} 
$b = Get-Service | Sort-Object status,displayname
$a
$b
```

you will see that it does not quite work. What happening here is that by default [Write-Output](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849921.aspx) is used to process the results. Write-Output writes stuff in the success pipeline, and powershell does unwrapping of the arrays. Then, I'm guessing the output system can't cope with the fact that output from get-service and select-object are of different types (and because of unwrapping they end up in the same array).

If you change the last line of your script to

```
Get-Service | Sort-Object status,displayname | ft
```

it will work. However note, that if you are going to pass around the results of your script, you better format it (ft) at the very end right before displaying. Basically, once you piped it to ft there is rarely a good reason to pass it anywhere else but for output (display or file).

**Update 2**

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/30/how-powershell-formatting-and-outputting-really-works.aspx) explains, that powershell uses the first object in the stream to determine how to format all of them. This explains the behaviour that we are observing.

Comment: I have added the full script, but I can't see how anything else would affect that command, it's in it's own space